# Formatar data no Android e SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

Estou com dificuldade em fazer o processo de setar a data atual do meu banco SQLite no atributo tipo `java.util.Date` do meu objeto.

A data do SQLite vem no formato "yyyy-MM-dd". Estou tentando converter para o formato aceito no tipo `java.util.Date` e que me permita utilizá-lo no meu Adapter porém ao rodar a aplicação está me retornando um erro dizendo que a data está nula. Realmente quando *debuguei* o App vi que a data não está sendo setada.

Segue a parte do código.

```
        Date data = null;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dataTeste = cursor.getString(1);
        try {
            data = dateFormat.parse(dataTeste);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        v.setDataVenda(data);
```

Obs: Na variável `dataTeste` o valor que está sendo preenchido é "2015-11-15".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mude a linha que estabelece o formato:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/DateFormat2.java).